# How to define a 3D surface from a set of points

Tags: finite-element

Sorry in advance if this question has already been asked, I found nothing to help.
I want to buid a 3D box whose top surface is topography. This topography is defined by a DEM i.e. a set of points (x,y,z) where z is the elevation and (x,y) are known on a cartesian grid.
How to include this set of points to generate a surface, meshed in triangles, to finally have a 3D mesh with tetraedra.

Thank you in advance for help,
Nathalie Glinsky

Comment: Of course I want to build this mesh with Gmsh !!

Comment: You could take a look at https://dealii.org/developer/doxygen/deal.II/step_53.html for inspiration.

Comment: I don't understand. If z is the elevation, you won't get tetrahedra, you would get "elevated triangles".

Answer (score 1):

Due to the fact you want to create a 3D triangulated surface out of a point cloud that is not necessary a closed surface (as I understand it's a topographical surface which is not closed anyway), the best method I can think of is using **Advancing Front Surface Reconstruction** method from CGAL: https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Advancing_front_surface_reconstruction/index.html